# Unable to get idAttribute to work in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Collection which specifies a Model which itself has an idAttribute set, as my backend uses a custom field for the primary key.  The code is like this:

```
var SearchItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'searchDefId'
});

var savedSearchesCollection = new SavedSearchesCollection({
    model: SearchItemModel
});
```

It's my understanding that I should be able to find the model by doing `that.collection.get(searchDefIdValue)`, but I can't.  Below, you can see that my collection has two models.  If I try to get the model based on Backbone's cid of 'c44', then it can find it no problem.  But if I try to search on the custom id field 'searchDefId', it can't find it.  I thought Backbone was supposed to copy the value of the idAttribute into id, but I don't see any 'id' field.

Also note that I can find the model using `that.collection.where({ searchDefId: data.searchDefId})[0]` but that seems like it may be more expensive.

[image: console output]

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you pass `options` as first argument to `SavedSearchesCollection` when `Backbone.Collection` expects it to be `models`. This also is proved by lack of `model` property on `that.collection`.

Try

```
var savedSearchesCollection = new SavedSearchesCollection([], {
    model: SearchItemModel
});
```

Comment: And normally you'd specify `model: SearchItemModel` when creating `SavedSearchesCollection` rather than when you instantiate the collection.

Comment: No luck.  I'm pretty sure that's an optional parameter.  Otherwise how would the view work at all.

Comment: @muistooshort: As with most things in Backbone, you can either specify it in the class or when you create the instance.  The Backbone docs themselves show it being done both ways: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

Comment: @TNguyen: Hence the *normally* qualification. I haven't seen many cases where it makes sense to not specify the `model` when defining the collection. If you're still having trouble then maybe you need to set up a functional example of your problem so that we can see what's really going on.

Comment: Strange. Looks like you're right, mu.  It shouldn't matter but specifying the model in the class rather than the instance made a difference.  If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.   FWIW, I always try to specify parameters in the instantiation.  It makes the class more generalized and is more semantic by stating "I want to create an object of this _type_ but with these specific _properties_".  The Collection class shouldn't need to know what model it's dealing with.  It shouldn't care.

Comment: @TNguyen, it is optional parameter, but it is also first parameter, so when giving second parameter you should set first parameter to something too. What version of backbone.js do you use?

Comment: v0.9.9.  But as mentioned, adding that parameter didn't make any difference.

Comment: @TNguyen There was bug connected with `{silent: true}` in v0.9.9 (it didn't updated object used by `get` method), maybe it causes your problem. Then it is strange that setting `model` in `Backbone.Collection.extend` solves your issue, since it should not differ. Anyway, I'm glad that your problem is solved and I would suggest you to update. [github issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2118)